# Angularjs : Using a directive from within another directive's link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In short, my question is how do I use a directive from inside another directive's link function?

---

Lets say I have a directive *`notification`*, whose main job is converting JSON data into a more readable format. I am using this directive independently in a few places already. It has an associated template which has takes the JSON data and converts it into readable format.

I also have another directive, which handles most of the application. This directive, lets call it *`client`* directive, must also be used to show notifications, exactly like the *`notification`* directive. The display of notifications is being handled within the **link** function of the *`client`* directive.

How do I **re-use** the notification directive within the client directive?

Comment: A small jsfiddle or plunker demonstrating would make this much easier to answer.

Comment: You should implement a factory or service to share behavior between those.

Comment: might also think about using broadcast events if that fits your needs. Need more specifics